# Pytorch squeeze and unsqueeze

Tags: python, pytorch

I don't understand what `squeeze` and `unsqueeze` do to a tensor, even after looking at the docs and [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57237352/what-does-unsqueeze-do-in-pytorch).

I tried to understand it by exploring it myself in python. I first created a random tensor with

```
x = torch.rand(3,2,dtype=torch.float)
>>> x
tensor([[0.3703, 0.9588],
        [0.8064, 0.9716],
        [0.9585, 0.7860]])
```

But regardless of how I squeeze it, I end up with the same results:

```
torch.equal(x.squeeze(0), x.squeeze(1))
>>> True
```

If I now try to unsqueeze I get the following,

```
>>> x.unsqueeze(1)
tensor([[[0.3703, 0.9588]],
        [[0.8064, 0.9716]],
        [[0.9585, 0.7860]]])
>>> x.unsqueeze(0)
tensor([[[0.3703, 0.9588],
         [0.8064, 0.9716],
         [0.9585, 0.7860]]])
>>> x.unsqueeze(-1)
tensor([[[0.3703],
         [0.9588]],
        [[0.8064],
         [0.9716]],
        [[0.9585],
         [0.7860]]])
```

However if I now create a tensor  `x = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4])`, and I try to unsqueeze it then it appears that `1` and `-1` makes it a column where as `0` remains the same.

```
x.unsqueeze(0)
tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
>>> x.unsqueeze(1)
tensor([[1],
        [2],
        [3],
        [4]])
>>> x.unsqueeze(-1)
tensor([[1],
        [2],
        [3],
        [4]])
```

Can someone provide an explanation of what squeeze and unsqueeze are doing to a tensor? And what's the difference between providing the arguements `0`, `1` and `-1`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "unsqueeze" do in Pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57237352/what-does-unsqueeze-do-in-pytorch)

Comment: Note: `-1` is just an alias for the final dimension, i.e. `1` in a 2d tensor.

Answer (score 47):

Here is a visual representation of what `squeeze`/`unsqueeze` do for an effectively 2d matrix:

[image]

When you are unsqueezing a tensor, it is ambiguous which dimension you wish to 'unsqueeze' it across (as a row or column etc). The [`dim`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html) argument dictates this - i.e. position of the new dimension to be added.

Hence the resulting unsqueezed tensors have the same information, but the *indices* used to access them are different.

Comment: This is an amazing diagram. Thanks

Comment: @iacob, this is fantastic. All of the outcomes with braces are correct. The illustrations of unsqueeze(1) and unsqueeze(2), however, should be switched.

Answer (score 18):

Simply put, `unsqueeze()` "adds" a superficial `1` dimension to tensor (at the specified dimension), while `squeeze` removes all superficial `1` dimensions from tensor.

You should look at tensor's `shape` attribute to see it easily. In your last case it would be:

```
import torch

tensor = torch.tensor([1, 0, 2, 3, 4])
tensor.shape # torch.Size([5])
tensor.unsqueeze(dim=0).shape # [1, 5]
tensor.unsqueeze(dim=1).shape # [5, 1]
```

It is useful for providing single sample to the network (which requires first dimension to be batch), for images it would be:

```
# 3 channels, 32 width, 32 height
tensor = torch.randn(3, 32, 32)
# 1 batch, 3 channels, 32 width, 32 height
tensor.unsqueeze(dim=0).shape
```

`unsqueeze` can be seen if you create `tensor` with 1 dimensions, e.g. like this:

```
# 3 channels, 32 width, 32 height and some 1 unnecessary dimensions
tensor = torch.randn(3, 1, 32, 1, 32, 1)
# 1 batch, 3 channels, 32 width, 32 height again
tensor.squeeze().unsqueeze(0) # [1, 3, 32, 32]
```

Answer (score 4):

1. `torch.unsqueeze(input, dim)` → `Tensor`

   ```
   a = torch.randn(4, 4, 4)
   torch.unsqueeze(a, 0).size()

   >>> torch.Size([1, 4, 4, 4])
   ```

   ```
   a = torch.randn(4, 4, 4)
   torch.unsqueeze(a, 1).size()

   >>> torch.Size([4, 1, 4, 4])
   ```

   ```
   a = torch.randn(4, 4, 4)
   torch.unsqueeze(a, 2).size()

   >>> torch.Size([4, 4, 1, 4])
   ```

   ```
   a = torch.randn(4, 4, 4)
   torch.unsqueeze(a, 3).size()

   >>> torch.Size([4, 4, 4, 1])
   ```
2. `torch.squeeze(input, dim=None, out=None)` → `Tensor`

   ```
   b = torch.randn(4, 1, 4)

   >>> tensor([[[ 1.2912, -1.9050,  1.4771,  1.5517]],

           [[-0.3359, -0.2381, -0.3590,  0.0406]],

           [[-0.2460, -0.2326,  0.4511,  0.7255]],

           [[-0.1456, -0.0857, -0.8443,  1.1423]]])
   ```

   ```
   b.size()

   >>> torch.Size([4, 1, 4])
   ```

   ```
   c = b.squeeze(1)
   ```

   ```
   b
   >>> tensor([[[ 1.2912, -1.9050,  1.4771,  1.5517]],

           [[-0.3359, -0.2381, -0.3590,  0.0406]],

           [[-0.2460, -0.2326,  0.4511,  0.7255]],

           [[-0.1456, -0.0857, -0.8443,  1.1423]]])
   ```

   ```
   b.size()
   >>> torch.Size([4, 1, 4])
   ```

   ```
   c
   >>> tensor([[ 1.2912, -1.9050,  1.4771,  1.5517],
           [-0.3359, -0.2381, -0.3590,  0.0406],
           [-0.2460, -0.2326,  0.4511,  0.7255],
           [-0.1456, -0.0857, -0.8443,  1.1423]])
   ```

   ```
   c.size()
   >>> torch.Size([4, 4])
   ```