# is unsqueeze(-1) equal to squeeze(1) in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I don't understand what it means to unsqeeze(-1). Ran into this piece of code [from HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/biu-nlp/abstract-sim-query) -

```
def encode_batch(model, tokenizer, sentences, device):
    input_ids = tokenizer(sentences, padding=True, max_length=512, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt",
                          add_special_tokens=True).to(device)
    features = model(**input_ids)[0]
    features = torch.sum(features[:, 1:, :] * input_ids["attention_mask"][:, 1:].unsqueeze(-1), dim=1) / torch.clamp(
        torch.sum(input_ids["attention_mask"][:, 1:], dim=1, keepdims=True), min=1e-9)
    return features
```

and I'm trying to understand what this calculation means.

I read that `unsqueeze` turns an n.d. tensor into an (n+1).d. one by adding an extra dimension of depth 1 and `squeeze` turns a n.d. tensor into an (n-1).d. one by removing one dimension of depth 1.

So what does it mean `unsqueeze(-1)` ?

according to this logic, if it adds -1 dimensions so it lower by one dimension so it means that `unsqueeze(-1) == squeeze(1)` ?

saw those examples [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61598771/pytorch-squeeze-and-unsqueeze) [second](https://linuxpip.org/pytorch-squeeze-unsqueeze/) and of course when over the documentation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter of `unsqueeze` and `squeeze` functions are not a number of dimensions to add/remove, it tells on which place should one dimension be added/removed. The parameter `-1` just means `in the end`, so `squeeze(-1)` would remove the last dimension and `unsqueeze(-1)` would add a new dimension after the current last.

Some examples:

```py
a = torch.randn((4, 4, 1))
a.shape               # torch.size([4, 4, 1])
a.squeeze(2).shape    # torch.Size([4, 4]), dimension 2 has been removed
a.squeeze(-1).shape   # torch.Size([4, 4]), last dimension has been removed (same effect)
a.unsqueeze(0).shape  # torch.Size([1, 4, 4, 1]), one new dimension as first
a.unsqueeze(1).shape  # torch.Size([4, 1, 4, 1]), one new dimension as second
a.unsqueeze(3).shape  # torch.Size([4, 4, 1, 1]), one new dimension as fourth
a.unsqueeze(-1).shape # torch.Size([4, 4, 1, 1]), one new dimension as last (same effect)
```