# What does unsqueeze do in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

```py
lower_bounds = torch.max(set_1[:, :2].unsqueeze(1), 
                         set_2[:, :2].unsqueeze(0))   #(n1, n2, 2)
```

This code snippet uses `unsqueeze(1)` for one tensor, but `unsqeeze(0)` for another. What is the difference between them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "unsqueeze" do in Pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57237352/what-does-unsqueeze-do-in-pytorch)

Comment: PyTorch supports numpy style [broadcasting semantics](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html). This explains why you get the observed shape of `lower_bounds` when the two arguments are unsqueezed along different dimensions.

Comment: The parameter is the direction to add the dimension in. See the documentation for more info.

Answer (score 3):

`unsqueeze` turns an n-dimensionsal tensor into an n+1-dimensional one, by adding an extra dimension of zero depth. However, since it is ambiguous which axis the new dimension should lie across (i.e. in which direction it should be "unsqueezed"), this needs to be specified by the [`dim`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html) argument.

Hence the resulting unsqueezed tensors have the same information, but the *indices* used to access them are different.

Here is a visual representation of what `squeeze`/`unsqueeze` do for an effectively 2d matrix, where it is going from a 2d tensor to a 3d one, and hence there are 3 choices for the new dimension's position:

[image]